# C++ variable shared by 2 files

Tags: c++, class, variables, pointers, share

I have 4 files:

- shared.h
- main.cpp
- something.h
- something.cpp

**shared.h:**

```
#ifndef SHARED_H
#define SHARED_H

int* sth;

#endif
```

---

**something.h:**

```
#ifndef SOMETHING_H
#define SOMETHING_H

class foo
{
   public:
      void printVar();
};

#endif
```

---

**something.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "something.h"
#include "shared.h"

using namespace std;

void foo::printVar()
{
    cout<<"Foo: "<<*sth<<endl;
};
```

---

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "shared.h"
#include "something.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sth=new int(32);

    foo x;
    cout<<"Main: "<<*sth<<endl;
    x.printVar();

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

Compiler returns multipe definition of *sth;

I added static modifier to the *sth and it compiles, but crashes. I changed the printings to print the adresses of pointer and I had program returned:

```
Main: 0x3e0f20
Foo: 0
```

Why is the foo's pointer not assigned? I want to assign it only once in main and then share in other files... How can I do this? Is it something with `extern` modifier?

Thanx for any replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use `extern`. Put `extern int* sth;` in the header, and then in *one* of the source files put `int* sth;`.

`extern` tells the compiler and linker that the actual variable/function definition is in another compilation unit (i.e. another source file).

Answer (score 5):

In shared.h you want to say:

```
extern int* sth;
```

to promise the compiler that sth exists somewhere.

Then in one (and only one) of the .cpp files you need to write:

```
int* sth;
```

To make it actually exists. In general you probably want to read about [the difference between declaration and definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration). As a rule of thumb you only want to declare things in header files, not define them.

When you wrote `static` previously you said that a variable with the same name exists in every file, but is "local" to each, i.e. the `sth` in main.cpp won't be the same as the `sth` in something.cpp.

Comment: and in other files I should use extern too or not?

Comment: @kittyPL in other files `#include` with the header file is sufficient. The `extern` is a promise to the compiler that it will exist somewhere when it needs it to. The `int* sth` without `extern` makes it actually exist in that specific place. You can write `extern int* sth` as many times as you like, but it's safer to only write it once in a single header file.

Comment: [Linker error] undefined reference to `sth' ... what now? It happens in the file without int *sth; Same with extern int* sth.

Comment: @kittyPL in which case you've not linked it against the file that does have `sth`, or simply forgotten to put the `int* sth;` in one and only one .cpp file - make sure they're both getting compiled into the same project properly. (Either that or it's a typo somewhere)

Comment: Worked when I put int* sth; in something.h... Is that becouse Its included before main?

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark `sth` as `extern` in the header to make it a *declaration*, and provide a *definition* for it in one of the cpp files. Otherwise, the variable is *declared* in each compilation unit where the header is included, which is not the effect you are looking for.

P.S. I assume that you know why *global variables* are not good, right?

Answer (score 2):

"***I have 4 files***".

Let me stop you right there. I agree that you have four files, but that's not really relevant. You have **two** *translation units*. A translation unit is the quantum of text that is fed into your compiler. Your translation units, let's call them *MAIN* and *SOMETHING*, consist of the result of preprocessing your files `main.cpp` and `something.cpp`, respectively.

After preprocessing, each of your translation units includes a line `int *sth;` This line declares *and defines* the variable `sth`.

The one-definition-rule requires that you have, in your entire program, exactly one (not more, not fewer) definition of `sth`. In order to accomplish this, you must have exactly one source-code line `int *sth;` in exactly one translation unit, and as many `extern int *sth;` as you require.

In your case, I would put `int *sth;` in MAIN and `extern int *sth;` in SOMETHING. Additionally, you can have as many extra copies of `extern int *sth;` as you feel like -- they won't hurt anything.

Now, back to your four files. You should put `extern int *sth;` in `shared.h`. This means that MAIN and SOMETHING will both have an `extern` line in them. You should also put `int *sth;` in `main.cpp`, so that MAIN will have the definition.

And there you are: MAIN and SOMETHING both have `extern` lines, so they are both referring to the same variable. MAIN also has a definition. so the `sth` variable has exactly one of those.

---

**Aside**: Why does `static int *sth;` in `shared.h` do the wrong thing?

Because each of the two translation units see their own `static` declaration. A `static` declaration reduces the linkage of the declared name to that single translation unit.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to make it a static global as that will create a local `sth` in every translation unit and you are only allocating it in one. This is why it crashed in `Foo::printVar` as in that scope it was an uninitialized pointer.

You want to declare it as `extern int* sth;` in the shared header then put `int* sth;` before main or in at least one place before it's used.

Actually, if you really need a globally accessible object, allocated on the heap, and you want to share it then it may be better as `extern std::shared_ptr<int> sth;`. Define it as `std::shared_ptr<int> sth;` the same way in one of the CPP files and call `std::make_shared` to allocate it. This way deallocating the memory will be handled automatically when the last object that uses it goes out of scope.